# scala - one line convert string split to vals

Tags: scala

I saw that following answer: [Scala split string to tuple](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14971901/scala-split-string-to-tuple), but in the question the OP is asking for a string to a List. I would like to take a string, split it by some character, and convert it to a tuple so they can be saved as vals:

`val (a,b,c) = "A.B.C".split(".").<toTupleMagic>`

Is this possible? This would be a conversion from an `Array[String]` to a `Tuple3` of `(String,String,String)`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It is unnecessary:

```
val Array(a, b, c) = "A.B.C".split('.')
```

Note that I converted the parameter to `split` from `String` to `Char`: if you pass a `String`, it is treated as a regex pattern, and `.` matches anything (so you'll get an array of empty strings back).

If you truly want to convert it to tuple, you can use [Shapeless](https://github.com/milessabin/shapeless).